# Desktop icon not vissible Compiz error?

Tags: compiz

I was updating ubuntu .Meanwhile all desktop icons disappear .
Noting is visible.

How can i recover that?.

Let me know any command which restore system or solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reset unity by doing

> unity --reset

followed by

> unity --reset-icons